# NSWindow how to set and get an identifier

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need something like a "tag"(iOS) for cocoa NSWindow. I have an "Error Message" NSWindow. I use the same window to display many custom messages. The problem is that if I release the window, this closes, so I need to keep a reference to the window in a NSDictionary, and in the close action, I am going to release the corresponding error window.

```
ErrorWindow *controllerWindow = [[ErrorWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ErrorWindow"];
[controllerWindow showWindow:self];
[controllerWindow setMessageText: message];
[controllerWindow setInformationText:info];

//If I release the window, it closes.
[controllerWindow release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to subclass NSWindow, so you can add your tag property:

```
/* MyWindow.h */
@interface MyWindow: NSWindow
{
@protected

    NSInteger _tag;
}

@property( assign, readwrite ) NSInteger tag;

@end

/* MyWindow.m */

#import "MyWindow.h"

@implementation MyWindow

@synthesize tag = _tag;

@end
```

In InterfaceBuilder, you'll then be able to set the class of your windows to MyWindow, instead of NSWindow.